# How to convert Luxon DateTime format into string or numbers?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, luxon

I am using the following code to set up a Luxon clock for my project use.

```
import { DateTime } from 'luxon';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

interface IProps {
  timezone: string;
  format: string;
  calendar?: string;
  daysOffset?: number;
}

const LiveDateTime: React.FC<IProps> = ({
  timezone,
  daysOffset,
  format,
  calendar,
}) => {
  const [timeLive, setTimeLive] = useState<DateTime>(DateTime.local());

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setTimeLive(
        DateTime.local()
          .setZone(timezone)
          .reconfigure({ outputCalendar: calendar })
          .plus({ days: daysOffset })
      );
    }, 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [timezone]);

  return <span>{timeLive?.toFormat(format)}</span>;
}; 
export default LiveDateTime;
```

Now, I am using this component in another place to define the month# of the current date.

```
const month = <LiveDateTime timezone={place?.timezone} format="M" />; // This returns '12' as a number in the UI (for December)
console.log(month)
getData(month); //this functions is supposed to return some data based on the given month.
//I get an error instead on this line that says, 'Argument of type 'Element' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
```

When I print this in the console, I get an entire react.element object. I need to be able to use '12' as a number (for December) in `getData()`for the `month` variable. **How can I covert this object into a number type or string type if necessary?**
P.S. I tried using pareInt(). doesn't work.

Comment: You shouldn't be returning a component just to convert the time. There are plenty of libraries that already do the job such as ``date-fns, luxon, moment``. Please feel free to choose the one that fits your use case and then convert the time in the component itself rather than creating a component to convert the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than having this logic in a React component, you should move it to a [custom React hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html) instead. This allows you to easily reuse its return value however you like.

```js
import { DateTime } from 'luxon';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const useLiveDataTime = ({
  timezone,
  daysOffset,
  format,
  calendar,
}: IProps) => {
  const [timeLive, setTimeLive] = useState<DateTime>(DateTime.local());

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setTimeLive(
        DateTime.local()
          .setZone(timezone)
          .reconfigure({ outputCalendar: calendar })
          .plus({ days: daysOffset })
      );
    }, 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [timezone]);

  return timeLive?.toFormat(format);
}; 

export default useLiveDataTime;
```

You can then retrieve the value as a string so you can pass it to other functions, or render it.

```js
import React from 'react';
import useLiveDataTime from '<path-to>/use-live-date-time';

const SomeComponent: React.FC = () => {
    const month = useLiveDataTime({ timezone: 'Europe/London', format: 'M' });
    console.log(month);
    getData(month);

    return <span>{month}</span>;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

As you're just using the month of the current time in the component you could just use 
 `const month = DateTime.local().setZone(place?.timezone).toFormat('M')` 
 adding a `.reconfigure({ outputCalendar: calendar })` and/or `.plus({ days: daysOffset })` if required

[image]

Comment: Already did it in the problem. It's not working. I need the output of the month as a string. not an object of different key value pairs.

Comment: Not sure what you mean sorry.  I've just added a screenshot to my answer.  If you go to the luxon website: https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/, and enter the above commands in the developer tools console you should get the month as a string as the output.  Maybe you're getting something different when running these commands in your project though?

Comment: This would be fine if you just wanted a month value that only changes on refresh (although as the month only changes 12 times a year this might be ok for your use case). juliomalves answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/70276633/9428323, is what you want if you want to keep the value constantly updated.  Although I think the useEffect in your and his example is only setup to run if the timezone changes, so you might need to change the dependency array [timezone] to an empty array []

Answer (score 0):

Even though I am still advocating my opinion that is in the comments, I totally respect if you want to continue the way you have chosen. Therefore, if you want to access the value of the component you can do so by calling the children which will hold the value in your case.

`console.log(month.props.children) // will return 12 as string`

Comment: Thank you. For the project requires the time/date needs to be used a lot in different circumstances with difference formats so I thought it easier to write the entire code once and then just call the component and pass the required formats, timezones, etc in its place. Anyways, so printing ```month.props.children``` doesn't help me because when I print month by itself, this is the type of object I get (added in next comment). How can I get '12' as a number from here?

Comment: month 
Object { "$$typeof": Symbol("react.element"), type: LiveDateTime(_ref)
, key: null, ref: null, props: {…}, _owner: {…}, _store: {…}, … }
"$$typeof": Symbol("react.element")
_owner: Object { tag: 0, key: null, index: 0, … }
_self: undefined
_source: Object { fileName: "C:\\...-card-grid.tsx", lineNumber: 37, columnNumber: 17 }
_store: Object { … }
key: null
props: Object { timezone: "America/New_York", format: "M" }
ref: null
type: function LiveDateTime(_ref)​
<prototype>: Object { … }

Comment: I already see that you have props in the month object. Can you console log to see what is that one?